# How to boot a Macbook Air into recovery with Windows keyboard and bad screen

Tags: macos, mac

A friend gave me their 2014 Macbook Air that has a bad screen.  They do not remember the password that they used with it and would like for me to recover the data from it for her.

I have it hooked up via the Thunderbolt/VGA adapter to an external adapter and can get to the login screen.  I have not been able to get it to boot into recovery mode however.  I am using a Windows keyboard (Spanish layout) and have tried to reboot the system in many different ways so it goes into Recovery Mode.  Alt-R, Alt alone, Windows-R, Windows-Alt-R but none of them work.  I will see a progress bar and it will then go to the regular login screen.

When I have tried to do this from a powered off state, my keyboard will not boot the laptop "in clamshell mode" by hitting a key nor will it turn on with a mouse key pressing as stated in another website.

Do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to get this thing into recovery mode so I can use Terminal to reset the password?

Comment: Is FileVault on? Do you see a padlock on that screen? Otherwise, Win/R should work. If it doesn't, borrow an Apple wired keyboard. I'm assuming you have to start it closed to force the external screen [I don't use Mac laptops so I'm not familiar with how that may work]... otherwise just use the internal keyboard.

Comment: No, FileVault is not on.  I am going to have to borrow an Apple wired keyboard from somewhere but I don't know where.  It doesn't help that I am outside the US in a country where I don't speak the language.  LOL

Comment: @tetsujin is correct COMMAND-R = WINDOWS-R on a windows keyboard. That will get you into recovery mode unless something else is wrong...